# Appropriate way to mock Func<>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

Hi I am trying to mock the following thing:

```
var result = _scope.Execute<FooService, IList<FooEntity>>(x => x.GetFooEntities(fooModel));
```

This is how I try to mock it:

```
_mockedScope
    .Setup(x => x.Execute<FooService, IList<FooEntity>>(f => f.GetFooEntities(It.IsAny<FooModel>())))
    .Returns(new List<FooEntity>)
```

But when I run the test it throws me an exception

> Unsupported expression: s => s.GetFooEntities(IsAny())

Any suggestions how can I mock it?

Here is an example what i want to moq

```
public class Test
{
    private readonly IScope _scope;

    public Test(IScope scope)
    {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        var foo = new FooEntity();

        Result<IList<Foo>> result =
            _scope.Execute<FooService, IList<Foo>>(
                "f",
                s => s.GetFoo(foo));
    }
}

public class Foo
{
}

public class FooEntity
{
}

public class FooService
{
    public List<Foo> GetFoo(FooEntity f);
}

public interface IScope
{
    Result<TResult> Execute<T1, TResult>(string temp, Func<T1, TResult> function);
}

public class Result<T>
{
    private Result(T value, Exception exception)
    {
        Value = value;
        Error = exception;
    }

    public Exception Error { get; }

    public T Value { get; }

    public bool HasError => Error != null;

    public static Result<T> Fail(Exception exception) => new Result<T>(default(T), exception);

    public static Result<T> Success(T value) => new Result<T>(value, null);
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] so we can copy and paste a complete sample into a console app.

Comment: Additionally, perhaps you could explain why you are trying to mock things the way you are, rather than mocking `FooService`?

Comment: there is no `s` in your examples. Can you show what `x` `f` and `s` are?

Comment: @mjwills i have added and example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While expressions are used by moq to setup mocks, you are trying to mock an expression. This tends to be very difficult with Moq but there are workarounds via matched arguments.

Assuming `Scope.Execute` method is defined like

```
public interface IScope {
    Result<TResult> Execute<T, TResult>(string temp, Func<T, TResult> function);
}
```

Use `It.IsAny` to allow for flexibility when setting up a mock that relies on an expression argument.

```
_mockedScope
    .Setup(x => x.Execute<FooService, IList<Foo>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<FooService, IList<Foo>>>()))
    .Returns(Result<IList<Foo>>.Success(new List<Foo>()));
```

The `It.IsAny<Func<FooService, IList<Foo>>>()` will cover   `s => s.GetFoo(foo)` in the invoked code.

Given

```
public class Test {
    private readonly IScope _scope;

    public Test(IScope scope) {
        _scope = scope;
    }

    public IList<Foo> Foo() {
        var foo = new FooEntity();

        Result<IList<Foo>> result = _scope.Execute<FooService, IList<Foo>>("f", s => s.GetFoo(foo));

        var value = result.Value;

        return value;
    }
}
```

The following complete example was used to demonstrate what was explained above

```
[TestClass]
public class ExpressionMock {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestFoo() {
        //Arrange
        var _mockedScope = new Mock<IScope>();

        _mockedScope
            .Setup(x => x.Execute<FooService, IList<Foo>>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<Func<FooService, IList<Foo>>>()))
            .Returns(Result<IList<Foo>>.Success(new List<Foo>()));

        var subject = new Test(_mockedScope.Object);

        //Act
        var actual = subject.Foo();

        //Assert
        actual.Should().NotBeNull();
    }
}
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the framework